# IFrame expands to fullscreen

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I was trying to embed my web application in an iframe.
I login, then go to some page, fill stuff there and then go to another page (x.aspx).
When x.aspx gets loaded, then somehow x.aspx occupies whole browser page and iframe vanishes.
This behaviour is noticable in FF3.6, Chrome, IE8.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks
Saarthak

Comment: You'll need to give us a little more information about what's going on in order for us to help you out. Example code that exhibits the probelm, for instance, would be a great way to solicit feedback.

Comment: I have made a temp.html with iframe source as my web application. Temp.html is on my desktop and my application is hosted. After I login, I fill up a form and then click submit (which does response.redirect). Then a.aspx opens. From a.aspx, I click a hyperlink which points to x.aspx. When I click on the hyperlink, the x.aspx expands to the whole page. Simple plain stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could contain a framebuster script. This is a small javascript that kicks the page out of a frame if it is framed.

Comment: What is a framebuster script? Can you give any example of it?

Comment: Hey Jort you were correct, there was indeed a small JS function causing that. Thanks